# Problem with Eigenfaces for face recognition in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, face-recognition

I'm trying to implement eigenfaces algorithm for face recognition in python using numpy and scikit learn for PCA then calculating the euclidean distance between the unrolled matrices produced by PCA.

The problem is that I don't get close distances between faces of the same person and large distances of different people:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from PIL import Image

person1_1 = Image.open('person1/1.jpg').convert('LA')
person1_2 = Image.open('person1/2.jpg').convert('LA')

person2_1 = Image.open('person2/1.jpg').convert('LA')
person2_2 = Image.open('person2/2.jpg').convert('LA')


person1_1 = np.asarray(person1_1)[:,:,0]
person1_2 = np.asarray(person1_2)[:,:,0]

person2_1 = np.asarray(person2_1)[:,:,0]
person2_2 = np.asarray(person2_2)[:,:,0]


pca = PCA(n_components=100)

person1_1_pca = pca.fit_transform(person1_1)
person1_2_pca = pca.fit_transform(person1_2)

person2_1_pca = pca.fit_transform(person2_1)
person2_1_pca = pca.fit_transform(person2_2)

print("Same person: {}".format(np.linalg.norm(np.ravel(person1_1_pca)-np.ravel(person1_2_pca))))
print("Different person: {}".format(np.linalg.norm(np.ravel(person1_1_pca)-np.ravel(person2_1_pca))))
```

The code produces:

```
Same person: 9293.360941013
Different person: 10218.849581657663
```

And sometimes I get larger distances for same person than distance of different people.

Where is the problem exactly

Comment: [Standardize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) your data before applying PCA. Also, the title is not in sync with the description. Please update accordingly

Comment: Can you rewrite it correctly,please?